# Socket Disconnection issue on Specific Mobile Network on JIO 5g network in INDIA

Tags: unity-game-engine, websocket, socket.io, game-development, multiplayer

Socket.io Version 4.7.2 in NODEJS

Best http socket.io client Version 2.8.6

Platform we are using Unity3d 2021.3.27f1

Hi Team,

we are using above version for creating socket connection for our game.

The socket is working fine on all other mobile networks and WIFI except JIO 5G network in INDIA.

Once we connect the socket using JIO 5G network. The socket get disconnected multiple times without any reason and this is happens only on JIO 5G Network.

Please let us know how to resolve it

It is very critical issue as 534 millions users using JIO

ERROR 1

Error in socket = {"message":"Request Finished with Error! Exception: Unable to read data from the transport connection: Connection reset by peer. at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x000ac] in <160ff2a7112f4c5e8071e4724342c6b6>:0 \n at BestHTTP.Extensions.ReadOnlyBufferedStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 size) [0x00069] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/Extensions/ReadOnlyBufferedStream.cs:48 \n at BestHTTP.Connections.BufferedReadNetworkStream.Read (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x00000] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/Connections/BufferedReadNetworkStream.cs:70 \n at BestHTTP.SecureProtocol.Org.BouncyCastle.Tls.RecordStream+Record.FillTo (System.IO.Stream input, System.Int32 length) [0x00002] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SecureProtocol/tls/RecordStream.cs:495 \n at BestHTTP.SecureProtocol.Org.BouncyCastle.Tls.RecordStream+Record.ReadHeader (System.IO.Stream input) [0x00000] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SecureProtocol/tls/RecordStream.cs:533 \n at BestHTTP.SecureProtocol.Org.BouncyCastle.Tls.RecordStream.ReadRecord () [0x00000] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SecureProtocol/tls/RecordStream.cs:207 \n at BestHTTP.SecureProtocol.Org.BouncyCastle.Tls.TlsProtocol.SafeReadRecord () [0x00060] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SecureProtocol/tls/TlsProtocol.cs:887 \n at BestHTTP.SecureProtocol.Org.BouncyCastle.Tls.TlsProtocol.ReadApplicationData (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x0004f] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SecureProtocol/tls/TlsProtocol.cs:748 \n at BestHTTP.SecureProtocol.Org.BouncyCastle.Tls.TlsStream.ReadByte () [0x00000] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SecureProtocol/tls/TlsStream.cs:76 \n at BestHTTP.WebSocket.Frames.WebSocketFrameReader.ReadByte (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/WebSocket/Frames/WebSocketFrameReader.cs:128 \n at BestHTTP.WebSocket.Frames.WebSocketFrameReader.Read (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x00000] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/WebSocket/Frames/WebSocketFrameReader.cs:50 \n at BestHTTP.WebSocket.WebSocketResponse.ReceiveThreadFunc () [0x00018] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/WebSocket/WebSocketResponse.cs:408 "}

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)

Carrom365.SocketController/<>c:b__38_2 (object) (at Assets/LUDO/Scripts/Common/SocketController.cs:219)

BestHTTP.SocketIO3.Socket/<>c__DisplayClass36_0`1:b__0 (object[]) (at Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SocketIO.3/Socket.cs:243)

BestHTTP.SocketIO3.Events.TypedEventTable:Call (string,object[]) (at Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SocketIO.3/Events/TypedEventTable.cs:95)

BestHTTP.SocketIO3.Socket:BestHTTP.SocketIO3.ISocket.EmitEvent (string,object[]) (at Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SocketIO.3/Socket.cs:483)

BestHTTP.SocketIO3.SocketManager:BestHTTP.SocketIO3.IManager.EmitEvent (string,object[]) (at Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SocketIO.3/SocketManager.cs:642)

BestHTTP.SocketIO3.SocketManager:BestHTTP.SocketIO3.IManager.EmitEvent (BestHTTP.SocketIO3.SocketIOEventTypes,object[]) (at Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SocketIO.3/SocketManager.cs:650)

BestHTTP.SocketIO3.SocketManager:BestHTTP.SocketIO3.IManager.EmitError (string) (at Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SocketIO.3/SocketManager.cs:662)

BestHTTP.SocketIO3.SocketManager:BestHTTP.SocketIO3.IManager.OnTransportError (BestHTTP.SocketIO3.Transports.ITransport,string) (at Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SocketIO.3/SocketManager.cs:483)

BestHTTP.SocketIO3.Transports.WebSocketTransport:OnError (BestHTTP.WebSocket.WebSocket,string) (at Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SocketIO.3/Transports/WebSocketTransport.cs:261)

BestHTTP.WebSocket.OverHTTP1:OnInternalRequestCallback (BestHTTP.HTTPRequest,BestHTTP.HTTPResponse) (at Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/WebSocket/Implementations/OverHTTP1.cs:206)

BestHTTP.Core.RequestEventHelper:HandleRequestStateChange (BestHTTP.Core.RequestEventInfo) (at Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/Core/RequestEvents.cs:569)

BestHTTP.Core.RequestEventHelper:ProcessQueue () (at Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/Core/RequestEvents.cs:437)

BestHTTP.HTTPManager:OnUpdate () (at Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/HTTPManager.cs:422)

BestHTTP.HTTPUpdateDelegator:CallOnUpdate () (at Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/HTTPUpdateDelegator.cs:286)

BestHTTP.HTTPUpdateDelegator:Update () (at Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/HTTPUpdateDelegator.cs:276

ERROR 2

Error in socket = {"message":"[BestHTTP.Connections.HTTP1Handler] Remote server closed the connection before sending response header! Previous request state: Processing. Connection state: Processing\n"}

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)

ERROR 3

Error in socket = {"message":"Unable to write data to the transport connection: The socket has been shut down.\n at BestHTTP.SecureProtocol.Org.BouncyCastle.Tls.TlsProtocol.SafeWriteRecord (System.Int16 type, System.Byte[] buf, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 len) [0x00036] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SecureProtocol/tls/TlsProtocol.cs:939 \n at BestHTTP.SecureProtocol.Org.BouncyCastle.Tls.TlsProtocol.WriteApplicationData (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x000e5] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SecureProtocol/tls/TlsProtocol.cs:1060 \n at BestHTTP.SecureProtocol.Org.BouncyCastle.Tls.TlsStream.Write (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32 offset, System.Int32 count) [0x00000] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/SecureProtocol/tls/TlsStream.cs:92 \n at BestHTTP.Extensions.WriteOnlyBufferedStream.Flush () [0x00009] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/Extensions/WriteOnlyBufferedStream.cs:35 \n at BestHTTP.HTTPRequest.SendOutTo (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x000b3] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/HTTPRequest.cs:1255 \n at BestHTTP.Connections.HTTP1Handler.RunHandler () [0x000b7] in /Users/aaryanshgawade/Carrom365Android/Assets/ThirdPartyPlugins/Best HTTP/Source/Connections/HTTP1Handler.cs:61 "}

[image]

tried on android and ios devices